# Safety SQL Dynamic Column Query in Postgresql (No Sql Injection)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, shapefile

I'm using Rails to get data from Postgresql by passing dynamic column and table name.

I cannot use ActiveRecord because the shape data that is imported from shapefile is dynamic both table and column name.
I have to use double quote with a column name in the query to avoid problem such column name: "addr:city" for example.

```
def find_by_column_and_table(column_name, shape_table_name)
            sql = "SELECT \"#{column_name}\" FROM \"#{shape_table_name}\" WHERE \"#{column_name}\" IS NOT NULL"
            ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_one(sql)
        end
```

2 examples of generated sql statement:

```
SELECT "place" FROM "shp_6c998258-32a6-11e0-b34b-080027997e00"
SELECT "addr:province" FROM "shp_6c998258-32a6-11e0-b34b-080027997e00"
```

I want to make sure there is no sql injection in the query.

Could anyone point me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to prevent injection, speed up your query and catch errors is to use positional parameters or stored proceedures. Anything less is asking for trouble.

- http://nasir.wordpress.com/2007/12/03/stored-procedures-and-rails/
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-expressions.html#AEN1834

Comment: Those don't work with SQL identifiers though.  We do a lot of this sort of thing in LedgerSMB in stored procedures, but both Perl and plpgsql have ways of handling this.  I don't know about Ruby.

Comment: I am voting this up because I don't really know of a better way to do this on ruby, but I would note that in pl/pgsql you would have to use EXECUTE, inline your dynamic identifiers, and use quote_ident(my_identifer) to escape them.